# Python: Convert Dataframe into a natural language text

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, nlp, stanford-nlp

We're implementing NLP solution, where we have a bunch of paragraphs text and tables. We've used google's burt for NLP, and it works great on text. However, if we ask a question whose answer lies in a table value then our nlp solution wouldn't work. Because it only works on natural language text (sentence, paragraph etc).

So, in order to get the answer from a table (dataframe) we're thinking to convert the whole dataframe into a natural language text which perserve the relation of each cell with its corresponding column name and row. For example:

```
+------------+-----------+--------+--+
| First Name | Last Name | Gender |  |
+------------+-----------+--------+--+
| Ali        | Asad      | Male   |  |
| Sara       | Dell      | Female |  |
+------------+-----------+--------+--+
```

Will become:

- First Name is Ali, Last Name is Asad, and Gender is Male
- First Name is Sara, Last Name is Dell, and Gender is Female

This will help us to find the right answer, for example, if I ask 'What's the Gender of 'Ali', then our NLP solution will give us the answer 'Male'.

I'm wondering is there any library available in python that converts a dataframe into a natural language text. Or shall I have to do it manually?

Many thanks

Comment: Is this example as simple as you're real project? I feel like it'd be pretty simple without a package, unless you want to do it for any variable dataframe?

Comment: There are cases when I've to transpose the dataframe. So, I was thinking to better find out any library that does that if not then I have done it manually.

Comment: What do you mean by transpose? What you're doing seems super straight-forward but I'm guessing I'm missing something...

Comment: For example, there are cases when a user design a table in a different way, let's say instead of creating the heading names of table on first row -- the user creates the heading at first column. Therefor, I have to transpose the table so that I could place the heading names on the first row of the dataframe. I hope my explanation doesn't confuse you, let me know if there are more questions :)

Comment: Gotcha, I'd suggest you add that to the question as it's no where to be seen, and is risking a downvote tbh.

Comment: I've explored various things, though rather more open ended. Depending on how elaborate you want to be, the approach at https://blog.ouseful.info/2020/01/07/simple-rule-based-approach-in-python-for-generating-explanatory-texts-from-pandas-dataframes/ demonstrates how to apply each row of a dataframe to a rune based system that then generates sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store it in a list you can easily do

```
text=[]
for index,rows in df.iterrows():
  a='First Name is {0}, Last Name is {1} and Gender is {2}'.format(df['First Name'] 
  [index],df['Last Name'][index],df['Gender'][index])
  text.append(a)
print(text)
```

You can then convert this list in natural language so that model can understand.

Comment: Hi @Ali Asad you can see the above suggestion.